# Bubble sort function for strings causes program crashes

Tags: c, string, pointers, bubble-sort

I don't know what's happening, every time I enter the second string in the code below, an error box pops up. I am using Codeblocks as compiler. Is it because I use pointer to pointer?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void sort_string(char **) ;
void main()
{
    char *name[5] ;
    int x =0;
    printf("Enter Names");
    for(x = 0 ; x < 5 ; x++)
    {   fflush(stdin);
        fgets( name[x], 100,  stdin);
    }
    sort_string(name);
    for( x = 0 ; x < 5 ; x++)
    {
        puts(name[x]);

    }


}
void sort_string(char *name[5])
{
    char *temp;
    int i , j ;
    for ( i = 4 ; i >=0; i--)
    {
        for ( j = 0 ; j <=i; j ++  )
        {
            if(strcmp(name[j] > name[j+1]))
            {
                temp = name[j+1];
                name[j+1] = name[j];
                name[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is an undefined operation... also where did you allocate memory to store these strings you're reading?

Comment: name[x] is pointer, need allocate memory.

Comment: Could you please explain your objective behind this statement `strcmp(name[j] > name[j+1])` as this is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments on the question, you need to allocate memory for the `name` elements.  One easy way is to note that you hard-code the length of a name to 99 chars (the limit passed to `fgets`) and change your array to

```
char name[5][100];
```

Once you do this, your string comparison isn't quite right.  Can you change

```
if (strcmp(name[j] > name[j+1]))
```

to

```
if (strcmp(name[j], name[j+1]) > 0)
```

This will show up another bug.  Your inner loop can run until `j=4`.  You then read/write beyond the end of your array when you access `name[j+1]`.  The easiest fix here will be to change the inner loop to exit one iteration sooner

```
for (j=0 ; j<i; j++)
//          < rather than <=
```

Comment: Thanks My prb is sloved..

Comment: Lesson learnt: you cannot blindly guess the C syntax and then fiddle out something resembling a program by trial & error. A programmer must actually know what every line in their code actually does.

Comment: @simonc.. Though the solution is fine, I am not sure hard-coding the length is a good idea. The original question was for an array of pointers for which I feel the solution should include a `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

From your code `char *name[5]` defines an array of `5` character arrays. Hence, when you perform `fgets( name[x], 100,  stdin);` , it is expected that memory is allocated for `name[x]` because `name[x]` is a pointer. Hence, the code could be modified as

```
for(x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
     name[x] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
     fgets( name[x], 100,  stdin);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Apart from this change, you need to incorporate the changes suggested by `simonc` on the `strcmp` i.e. the condition becomes `if(strcmp(name[j], name[j+1]) > 0)` and the looping construct which is changed to `for ( j = 0 ; j <i; j ++  )`. With these 2 modifications apart from the `malloc` above, your code will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

fgets( name[x], 100,  stdin);

You are copying it into an unallocated memory.

char *name[5] ;

It will only create a character pointer array of size 5.
You have to initialize value to that pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't allocating `name[]` correctly.  Most modern languages take care of allocating strings and things for you, but C is old school and you need to manage it yourself.  There are a few ways to do this.

```
char name[5][100];
```

This allocates on the stack a local 2-dimensional array 500 bytes long.  `name[0]` refers to a 100-char array at the beginning of the allocation.  `name[1][3]` refers to the fourth character in the second 100-char buffer which is the 104th byte in `name`.  `name[4]` is the last 100-char array.

```
char *name[5];
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    name[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
}
```

Here, `name` is an array of 5 `char *` values, probably 40 bytes long.  Each of these pointers points to a separate 100-byte allocation on the heap.  You refer to the bufferrs and characters within them in the same way as `name[5][100]` above, even though it's an array of allocations instead of a 2-dimensional array.